# maxmind geoip country database installation instructions in mysql database for windows os

Tags: mysql

I have downloaded maxmind country database from there site [Country database CSV](http://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/geoip2/geolite2/).
Now i want to install this database in mysql database.i read instruction given on there documentation page but i am confused.
How to install this database in mysql database?

here is stuff that i have tried..

```
 CREATE DATABASE geoip;

 USE geoip;

 CREATE TABLE geocountry (
        start_ip CHAR(15) NOT NULL,
        end_ip CHAR(15) NOT NULL,
        start_long INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
        end_long INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
        country_code CHAR(2) NOT NULL,
        country_name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
        );


LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\geocountry.csv'
INTO TABLE geocountry
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
(start_ip, end_ip, start_long,end_long,country_code,country_name);
```

[image]

Comment: If what you tried didn't work, you will need to give us a hint of what went wrong, like an error message, perhaps.

Comment: finally I loaded csv file in database now but in some rows it adding double quote's(") like for column country_name it adding "Korea

Comment: I'm not familiar with MySQL, but what you need to do is specify that the field delimiter includes the double quotes, or process the CSV to escape commas within the fields. The raw input is `"119.17.64.0","119.17.127.255","1997619200","1997635583","KR","Korea, Republic of"` and the comma within the country name is being picked up as a field separator.

Comment: I've replaced link to direct down with link to information about the file (the direct download link is on that info page) as this seems friendlier to the provider and potentially more helpful to some viewers here.